# How can I set the Backgoundcolor of an AX2012 Action Pane Button

Tags: x++, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm trying to set the background color of an Action Pane Button so I changed the init-Method to this:

```
public void  init()
{
    super();
    myButton.colorScheme(FormColorScheme::RGB);
    myButton.backgroundColor(WinAPI::RGB2int(255,0,0));
}
```

but myButton (AutoDeclaration is on) does not become red.

Even when I set these properties by hand, the color does not change.
The Button has an Action, where the Image is defined. But removing that won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to provide a custom background color for buttons in the action pane.

If you just want the button to look different, you can set the `ToogleButton` property to `Check` and the `ToggleValue` property to `On` to give it a difference appearance, you will also need to add code in the clicked method for the button to prevent it toggling to `Off`. This will give the button a different background color, but you won't have any control over the color used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not really happy with that. But at least I can stop trying now. Possibly there is a completely different way zu highlight that function.